# Dealing with Protractor.js' Asynchronous nature

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, protractor

I'm struggling dealing with Protractor's asynchronous nature.

On different connections or browsers, it seems that elements are sometimes found, sometimes not, depending on my connection speed.

Short of using .then() callbacks, what options are available to me within Protractor to deal with it's Async issues to make sure elements are fully loaded before moving onto the next action?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an AngularJS app under test and you don't change the `ignoreSynchronization` value?

Comment: I did add browser.ignoreSynchronization = true because that's waht was already there, is that not correct/is that messing me up? I didn't look to into it

Comment: You should not tweak `ignoreSynchronization` without it being needed explicitly. Try not changing it and run your tests. Do you get into any issues?

Comment: now I get the following issue after taking it out: Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"

Comment: A simple advice - if you don't have an angular.js app, don't use protractor. If you have an angular.js app, don't touch `ignoreSynchronization` and keep it on `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems like that.. to resolve it, if a element depends of a asynchronous call to be showed, I always put a browser wait before.

```
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element(by.id('elementId'))), 3000);
element(by.id('elementId').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399523/removing-browser-ignoresynchronization-true-causes-angular-could-not-be-found), it would seem you're testing a non-angular application. Hence, you *will* want to use `ignoreSynchronization`.

And thus, you'll need to handle async and all it's quirks yourself. Eg. using `then()` callbacks, and `ExpectedConditions` and the like.