# removing browser.ignoreSynchronization = true causes "angular could not be found on the window"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I need to remove browser.ignoreSynchronization from my protractor files. However, doing so causes an "angular could not be found on the window" error. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Best.
Austin

Comment: why do you think that it's necessary to remove this?  is it interfering with one of your tests?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. It means the app you're testing isn't an [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) app. I.e. does not include Angular code.

`ignoreSynchronization` is used when testing non-Angular apps.